# Multi threading with CachedThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading

I have server-client communication architecture where there is **one** server and **150** clients.

The server-client communication happens via Java NIO where all the clients send some or the other data every 10 seconds.
Previously we used to queue all the process messages and process all those in a single thread, as the number of clients are more so as the messages, server is not able to process all the messages instantly and there is a delay in processing in turn data loss.
So I have thought of implementing `CachecThreadPool` to process the tasks simultaneously as soon as they come, picked `CachedThreadPool` over `FixedThreadPool` because the tasks are short lived and many in number, below is the code for that.
The thread which receives messages from client calls `ProcessorClass.processData(message)` as soon as it receives the message.

```
public class ProcessorClass{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ProcessorClass.class);
    static ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public static void processData(StringBuffer message) {
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    LOGGER.info("Queue size:"+executor.getQueue().size());
                    if (message != null){
                        processMessage(message);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Error happened in run() method" + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        };
        executor.execute(task);
    }
    public static void processMessage(StringBuffer message){
        // all the processing of message such as DB operations goes here.
    }
}
```

Doubts:

1. How CachedThreadPool stores the message in the queue because i haven't defined any explicitly.
2. Should i chose FixedThreadPool over this?
3. Should i make my `processMessage()` method **synchronized**?

All the suggestions and review comments are welcome.

Comment: Your code is missing something. What's inside `processMessage`? Is it thread-safe? More context usually leads to a better question and better answers.

Comment: inside processMessage i am performing database operations by parsing the message received,as far as i know i am not doing any operations which deals with shared objects inside that method.

Answer (score 1):

1. The thread pool is not storing messages on a queue; it is storing `Runnable` tasks.  However, each `Runnable` task has access to the effectively final `StringBuffer message` variable from the calling context.
2. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957382/fixedthreadpool-vs-cachedthreadpool-the-lesser-of-two-evils).  Each is a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, just with different parameters to control how many threads are created and the type of queue.  I would lean in favour of the `FixedThreadPool` with 1 thread for each CPU core, but many other factors can and will impact that; profile to be sure.
3. **No**.  Making `processMessage()` synchronized will mean you are single threaded ... worse, because the overhead of multiple threads being scheduled to process the task queue in a single threaded fashion.   At 150 messages/10 seconds, with one thread the function would need to complete in 66ms.  If you have 8 cores, with 1 thread per core, each thread could take a leisurely 500ms to process the message, as long as they can run independently.  You may have parts of `processMessage` that you may need to make synchronized, but you’ll want to make those regions as small and fast as possible.

Other comments:

A `StringBuffer` is a mutable object;  since `message` is being passed to another thread, for safety, I’d want the message to be transformed into a immutable `String` so the caller doesn’t clear the message buffer while the executor thread is processing it.

`processMessage()` does not need to be `public`; `private` would be more appropriate.

It looks like `executor` should be `private` and `final` as well.